# How to handle the call back on Swift using two for loop

Tags: ios, swift3, swift4

I need to get the response from API ,

but I don't know the call back handle when more than a loop

if anyone know , share the sample regarding this.

alsoI need to know when all the services are done

```
let managedObject = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext
for articleItem in (self.articleListArray) {
    for item in (articleItem.tags)! {
        let aTag = ArticleSection.entityWithId(itemID: item, managedObjectContext: managedObject)
        if (aTag.title == nil) {
            let networkManager = NXTNetworkManager()
            networkManager.releaseTag(article: aTag, success: { (formData) in

            }) { (error) in

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Only you know the response format. But looking from your API structure, it seems like you have two callbacks. One for success and another for failure. So just handle the success in the success and failure in the failure?

Comment: your call is async so its takes delay for call back but your functional will completed before completion ,initally break your loop once your condition is met, then call your networkManager in outside the loop,

Comment: Its better to change api. Pass `articleItem.tags` as argument. So that on app side, we can avoid multiple network calls. *NB: IDK the exact requirements. Just a suggestion.*

Answer (score 0):

You can use custom delegate to handle call back response from API.